# Как заблокировать экран для касаний в Android

Tags: android

Искал информацию, но все с что находил, связано с блокировкой телефона, т.е. при нажатии на View происходит блокировка телефона. Мне же нужно, чтобы при нажатии на View происходила блокировки экрана от touch'ей пользователя, а в углу, к примеру, была кнопка, которая может его разблокировать по паролю. Что-то подобное реализовано в MxPlayer для блокировки экрана при просмотре видео. Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение проблемы.

Comment: Блокировка экрана только в приложении?

Comment: @Suvitruf Да, чтобы пользователь не мог работать с планшетом. Необходимо для работы планшетов в публичных местах, где на планшете, к примеру, крутится видео и чобы никто не смог производить с планшетом никаких действий.

Comment: Но юзер может свернуть это приложение ведь?

Comment: @Suvitruf смотрел в MxPlayer. Там при нажатии на кнопку с замком происходит блокировка тачей и появляется кнопка в углу для разблокировки. Тачи блокируются полностью, свайп с верхнего края экрана для вызова меню не срабатывает - появляется только вехний бар с сетью, временем и т.д. Нижние кнопки домой, назад, свернуть при этом тоже не откликаются. Сам бар с нижними кнопками появляется на секунду и потом исчезает, т.е. по факту, все залочено, остается только разблокировать нажатием по кнопке.

Comment: @Suvitruf  Да, и еще, при блокировке устройства от кнопки на корпусе и дальнейшей разблокировке, блокировка тачей пропадает. Было бы хорошо побороть и эту проблему.

Comment: Почитайте тут, пару лет назад уже обсуждалось http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549478/how-to-disable-home-and-other-system-buttons-in-android